# Ruby: share a class variable between a parent class and its subclasses

Tags: ruby, inheritance, class-variables

I'm trying to do what I described in the title because I want to use the subclasses' class variable value in the parent. Actually, I found a way to do it but I feel like I can do something nicer. Here is my current code:

```
class Parent
  def self.test_settings
    const_set "PATH", "/tmp/#{self.name}"
  end
end

class Sub1 < Parent
  def self.name
    "one"
  end
  test_settings if Rails.env.test?
end

class Sub2 < Parent
  def self.name
    "two"
  end
  test_settings if Rails.env.test?
end
```

My original version - that **didn't work**, is:

```
class Parent
  def self.test_settings
    const_set "PATH", "/tmp/#{@@name}"
  end
  test_settings if Rails.env.test?
end

class Sub1 < Parent
  @@name = "sub1"
end

class Sub2 < Parent
  @@name = "sub2"
end
```

I'll explain: I used a class method instead of a variable (@@name) which I tried before unsuccessfully. In addition I had to move the function call `test_settings if Rails.env.test?` to the subclasses because it would consider `self` as the parent class if I place this code there.

I would appreciate any suggestions how to improve it and why my original idea(using @@name and call the test_settings method in the parent class) doesn't work.

Comment: do you have same typos(`Paernt` instead of `Parent`, `Rail` instead of `Rails`) in your code?

Comment: `@@name` is called the *class variable*, which will give you the most recent value, and it is a _shared variable_ across the inheritance. Other question I didn't get sorry. :)

Comment: Note that implementing `self.name` overwrites / shadows [`Module#name`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-name)

Answer (score 1):

This avoids using class variables, but IMHO is clearer, and avoids potential problems alluded to [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080720172603/http://sporkmonger.com/2007/2/19/instance-variables-class-variables-and-inheritance-in-ruby)

```
class Parent
  def self.test_settings(name)
    const_set "PATH", "/tmp/#{name}"
  end
end

class Sub1 < Parent
  test_settings("sub1") if Rails.env.test?
end

class Sub2 < Parent
  test_settings("sub2") if Rails.env.test?
end



irb(main):042:0> Sub1::PATH
=> "/tmp/sub1"
irb(main):043:0> Sub2::PATH
=> "/tmp/sub2"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it work, you should define `@@name` in `Parent` class:

```
class Parent
  @@name = nil

  def self.test_settings
    const_set "PATH", "/tmp/#{@@name}"
  end
end

class Sub1 < Parent
  @@name = 'sub1'
  test_settings
end

class Sub2 < Parent
  @@name = 'sub2'
  test_settings
end

puts Sub1::PATH #=> /tmp/sub1
puts Sub2::PATH #=> /tmp/sub2
```

Otherwise Ruby will tell you that `@@name` is uninitialized.

Comment: Watch out with this one - @@name will have the value 'sub2' in both of the subclasses once this snippet has run